# Reading a custom object's data to populate a table view

Tags: ios, swift

I've set up a custom Company object like this:

```
class Company: NSObject {

var companyName: String
var companyLogo: String
var stockPrice: String
init(companyName:String, companyLogo:String, stockPrice:String) {
self.companyName = companyName
self.companyLogo = companyLogo
self.stockPrice = stockPrice
}
}
```

And I give each object its properties like this:

```
func companyList() -> [Company] {
let apple = Company(companyName: "Apple", companyLogo: "AppleLogo", stockPrice: prices[0])
let google = Company(companyName: "Google", companyLogo: "GoogleLogo", stockPrice: prices[1])
let twitter = Company(companyName: "Twitter", companyLogo: "TwitterLogo", stockPrice: prices[2])
let tesla = Company(companyName: "Tesla", companyLogo: "TeslaLogo", stockPrice: prices[3])
let samsung = Company(companyName: "Samsung", companyLogo: "SamsungLogo", stockPrice: prices[4])

return [apple, google, twitter, tesla, samsung]
}
```

I'd like to populate a tableview's labels with the Company object's data - for example I want to set the tableview's labels to read all the company names - with a hardcoded array of company name strings (ie. not as an object) it's as easy as:

```
cell.textLabel.text = companyNames[indexPath.row]
```

How can I do the same thing now that I have a Company object?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to convert one array (Companies) to another array (Company names). This is a good use for `map`:

```
let companyNames = companyList().map({ $0.companyName })
cell.textLabel.text = companyNames[indexPath.row]
```

Alternatively, you could just get the right company first, then its name:

```
cell.textLabel.text = companyList()[indexPath.row].companyName
```

Which doesn't need an intermediate array, so I'd suggest the 2nd choice.

Comment: Thanks Connor... I tried both of those and got index out of range crashes, I'm not entirely sure where that problem lies but it could be my prices array since that has to wait for the stock prices to be fetched.

Comment: That's almost certainly the cause. If you're fetching items from somewhere you need to wait until that call is done to load your table.

Comment: Wouldn't putting cell.textLabel.text inside the completion handler for the stock price fetcher take care of that? I tried doing just that and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a `UITableViewCell` subclass that takes `Company` property…

```
CompanyCell: UITableViewCell {

   var company: Company {
        didSet {
           textLabel.txt = company.companyName
        }
   }
}
```

Then in your view controller,

```
cell.company = companies[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

- add a property to your view controller `var companies: [Company]!`
- populate the property when new data about companies become available `companies = companyList()`
- when prompted for number of rows in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, return `companies.count`
- set the `cell.textLabel.text = companies[indexPath.row].companyName` and other values in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`
- create custom cell if the default with 2 labels and and image does not suffice

Comment: Ok so I added the property at the top of the view controller, put companies = companyList() inside viewDidLoad (this is the step I'm unsure about, bear with me I'm pretty new), set the number of rows to companies.count and then set the text labels. I got an error: stored property "companies" without initial value prevents synthesized initializers

Comment: Adding it to viewDidLoad is fine. I suspect than in real world app you will want to update it periodically or on demand from internet, so you will have to add some other logic to accommodate that. As far as the error message - you need to initialize the property in init. Since you are initializing it in viewDidLoad which is called later than init, make it optional. See the updated answer.